# jquery toggleClass selects all list items instead of one

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I've searched for similar issues on Stack, but haven't found this specific (and I'm sure common) issue.

I have a list of items that have a default class. I want to use toggleClass to add a rollover effect. The problem is that all of the lis are getting the toggled class instead of just the one that is being hovered.

```
<ul>
 <li class="my-class"><div id="my-item>1</div></li>
 <li class="my-class"><div id="my-item>2</div></li>
 <li class="my-class"><div id="my-item>3/div></li>
</ul>

$('.my-class, li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#my-item').toggleClass('project-home-title-hover');
});
```

Comment: The html attribute `id` should be unique, i.e. multiple elements cant have the same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope the selector with `this`.  Also remove the comma between `.my-class` and `li` and change the selector to `li.myclass`.  Also `my-item` should be a class instead of an id, ids must be unique. The markup also need some work there are unclosed end tags for one of the divs and missing quotes.

```
$('li.my-class').on('mouseenter  mouseleave', function() {
    $('.my-item', this).toggleClass('project-home-title-hover');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li class="my-class"><div class="my-item">1</div></li>
 <li class="my-class"><div class="my-item">2</div></li>
 <li class="my-class"><div class="my-item">3</div></li>
</ul>
```

**Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SEMKr/1/

Comment: The `li` has the class. Should it be `li.my-class`?

Comment: I have never seen the use of `this` to scope a selector.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem. Then how would I additionally add "mouseleave" so that the user doesnt then have to hover of the item again to remove the class? I was instructed to use "mouseenter/leave" instead of "hover".

Comment: @MarcAudet See the fiddle for now.  Let me search the documentation.

Comment: @MarcAudet See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1 its the optional context argument

Comment: @MarcAudet you can scope any selector by passing in a second parameter to `$()`.  The syntax is `$('selector', elementOrJQueryObject)`.  In this case, since we're inside an event handler, `this` refers to the `event.target` element, which is the `<li>`, so we can pass it in as the scope parameter.

Comment: @JasonWagner See the updated Javascript. Its as simple as adding `mouseleave` to the list of events. Fiddle also updated.

Comment: @MarcAudet  Awesome, thanks for the fiddle and quick response.

Comment: @JasonWagner I provided the fiddle. :)

Comment: Based on earlier comments, I discovered `jQuery( selector [, context ] )` in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context It is one of those things I never paid much attention to, so thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @MarcAudet Glad we could help.  I find using the context very useful.